# Поворот SVG картинки при нажатии на кнопку на чистом CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Мне необходимо при нажатии на кнопку поворачивать `SVG объект` на 45 градусов.

Набросал код по одному туториалу, но он не работает. Может кто подскажет, что я делаю не так или где можно почитать о моей проблеме?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.btn-menu {
  /*  background-color: blue; */
  font-family: HelveticaNow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  top: 70px;
  right: 140px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker {
  /*   display: none; */
}

.menu-button {
  top: 60px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.menu-image {
  position: fixed;
  right: 150px;
}

.menu-text {
  /* меню welcome */
  /*  display: inline; */
  /* position: fixed; */
  top: 70px;
  right: 150px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: HelveticaNow;
  font-size: 10.5pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transform: scaleY(0.8);
  float: left;
}

.menu-icon {
  /*  display: inline; */
  /* position: fixed; */
  float: left;
  top: 70px;
  right: 117px;
}

.menu-icon:hover {
  /*  transform-origin: center; */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu {}

.hidden-menu-ticker~.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animationFadeOut 1s;
  right: -400px;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  opacity: 1;
  animation: animationFadeIn 1s;
  right: 25px;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.menu-icon {
  /*  position: fixed; */
  /*  top: 20px; */
  /*  transform: translateX(20px); */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes icon-animationOn {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes icon-animationOff {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
  <label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
 <span class="menu-button"></span>
 <span class="menu-image">
 <div class="menu-text">WELCOME</div><div class="menu-icon"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3033-3163-4338-a630-323334383934/plusClosed.svg" width="15"></object></div>
 </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все потому, что селектор с `~` ищет элементы на том же уровне вложенности. Вложенные элементы, т.е. те, что расположены на уровень ниже в выборку не попадут.

**Код, который иллюстрирует это:**

```css
h2,
p {
  background-color: #f88;
}

div~h2,
div~p {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Уровень вложенности 2</h2>
  <p>Элемент обернут в DIV. Его уровень вложенности выше.</p>
</div>
<h2>Уроверь вложенности 1</h2>
<p>Уровень вложенности тот же что и у DIV</p>
```

**Исправленный ваш код:**

```css
body {
  background-color: #cff;
}

.btn-menu {
  /*  background-color: blue; */
  font-family: HelveticaNow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  top: 70px;
  right: 140px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker {
  /*   display: none; */
}

.menu-button {
  top: 60px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.menu-image {
  position: fixed;
  right: 150px;
}

.menu-text {
  /* меню welcome */
  /*  display: inline; */
  /* position: fixed; */
  top: 70px;
  right: 150px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: HelveticaNow;
  font-size: 10.5pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  transform: scaleY(0.8);
  float: left;
}

.menu-icon {
  /*  display: inline; */
  /* position: fixed; */
  float: left;
  top: 70px;
  right: 117px;
}

.menu-icon:hover {
  /*  transform-origin: center; */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.btn-menu {}

.hidden-menu-ticker~.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: animationFadeOut 1s;
  right: -400px;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked~.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  opacity: 1;
  animation: animationFadeIn 1s;
  right: 25px;
}

.hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu object {
  /*  position: fixed; */
  /*  top: 20px; */
  /*  transform: translateX(20px); */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes icon-animationOn {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes icon-animationOff {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker">
<label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
 <span class="menu-button"></span>
 <span class="menu-image">
   <div class="menu-text">WELCOME</div>
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3033-3163-4338-a630-323334383934/plusClosed.svg" width="15"></object>
    </div>
 </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Всё работает, огромное спасибо!

Comment: Получается мне необходимо было указать уровень вложенности? А почему тогда .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu object { а не .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu div object {? Div можно не указывать в иерархии? Если Вас не затруднит, подскажите, пожалуйста, где об этом можно посчитать?

Comment: @AndrewGor https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/50759/ надеюсь после прочтения и пары экспериментов вопросов нет останется.